# Count values inside sublists separately

Tags: list-manipulation

I've the following problem: given a nested list like this:

```
a={{1,2,3,2,1},{2,3,4,6,4,3,2},{4,5,12,5,4}};
```

How can I count, in each sublist, those values that are following a particular rule, like the values bigger or equal than half the maximum value in the sublist?
In this case I'd like a result like this:

```
b={3,5,1}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `Count[#, x_ /; x >= Max[#]/2] & /@ a`?

Comment: counter[sublist_] := Length[Select[sublist, (# >= Max[sublist]/2) &]];        counter /@ a

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To settle this:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3, 2, 1}, {2, 3, 4, 6, 4, 3, 2}, {4, 5, 12, 5, 4}};
Count[#, x_ /; x >= Max[#]/2] & /@ a
   {3, 5, 1}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing and setteling. I appreciate your A&Q's very much!

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively:

```
Tr[UnitStep[# - Max[#]/2]] & /@ a
```